# Is it possible to unload an ActiveRecord association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I encountered a situation where a model being saved in flash caused a `marshall data too short` error, and discovered that the reason for this is that a huge association was being loaded and then when put into the session the data was too large for the field.

My classes look something like this:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :city
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :states
  has_many :locations
end

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :cities
  has_many :locations
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :locations
end
```

Unfortunately, the validation in `Location` accesses `self.state.cities`, which loads all the cities for that state into memory (in this case, over 1000 records). As such, when the `Location` object is passed through `flash`, it causes the above error.

I realize that the code can be refactored to not access the association (in fact, that's what I've done at the moment), but I was wondering if there was any way to *unload* the association data from memory (without deleting it from the database, of course).

This project is using Rails 2.3.4 and unfortuately I am unable to upgrade it at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1: Solution to the stated problem:**

To empty the loaded association data, use the `target` method on the association:

```
location.state.cities.target=[]
```

If you access the `cities` now:

```
location.state.cities
=> []
```

**Part 2: Clumsy way to avoid the problem:**

Avoid loading the association while accessing `cities`. Use

```
self.state.cities.all
```

Instead of

```
self.state.cities
```

**Part 3: Something smells fishy:**

Why are you storing objects in to flash? Flash is generally meant for sending text  messages. If you assign non strings to flash you will run in to the cookie size limit in no time.

Also when you are validating why do you need to load all the cities? Does this mean you are validating in Ruby? Can you post the validation code. In most cases you can optimize this by moving validation to DB.

**Edit: Extended the answer based on the comment**

I follow this pattern in Rails 2.3.x. The variables I want to access in the view associated with `edit` action is  always a subset of variables available in `update` action.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :init_data, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, 
                                      :destroy, :show]
  def update
    @product.attributes = params[:product]
    if @product.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully saved the product."
      redirect_to  product_path(@product)
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

private
  def init_data
    switch(action.to_sym)
      when :new, :create
        @product = Product.new(params[:product])
      when :edit, update, :destroy, :show 
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end
  end    
end
```

Comment: I was using `state.cities.find_by_name`, so instead are you suggesting using `state.cities.all(:conditions => {:name => ...})`? Also, in terms of flash, I temporarily put the object into flash so that changes are retained when transitioning from `update` (with an error state) back to `edit`.

Comment: If you use `render` instead of `redirect` all the variables defined in `update` should be accessible in `edit`.  The `state.cities.find_by_name` call does not cache the association array. Some other parts of your code must be loading the association. The association results are cached ONLY when you call `state.cities` explicitly.

Comment: the only other possibility would be a call to `state.cities.create`... so I'm not sure. Maybe something was tweaked beyond 2.3.4? The reason I used `redirect_to` instead of `render` was so that I wouldn't have to setup the variables needed in the view in both actions; is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look.